# document.hasOwnProperty("hidden") returns false but document has the property hidden

Tags: javascript, object, dom, hasownproperty

I'm trying to check if document has 'hidden' property using document.hasOwnProperty but it always returns false in Chrome (74).

I've tried Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty but that too returns false. When I tried to stringify and parse back document I got back Location object as a property.

```js
console.log(document.hasOwnProperty("hidden"));
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(document, "false"));
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(document)));
console.log(typeof document.hidden !== "undefined");
console.log(document.hidden);
console.log(Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(document, "hidden"));
console.log(Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(document, "location"));
```

Shouldn't `hasOwnProperty` check if an object has a property irrespective of the object type? I apologize if the question has already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is to check whether a certain property is defined on the *instance* itself and is not inherited through its `prototype`.

In the case of `document`, it rightfully returns `false` since the `hidden` property is actually defined on the `Document` interface and not on the instance itself.

(thanks to @Jonas Wilms for clarification)

Comment: No, it is not. It is defined on the [Document interface.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

Comment: Why did you delete this instead of updating it to say that the property is on `Document`?

Comment: @Ry-, Indeed, I was too quick to delete.

Comment: Thank you for the input @haim770. I would like to ask if there's a way to check the property exists with Document, as I've tried and still get false for ```hidden```

Comment: @shrys, What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's wrong with `typeof document.hidden !== "undefined"`?

Comment: I could do that or as @Ry- suggested I could use ```typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'hidden') == "object"```.  I actually wanted to keep it generic for other browsers as well which have a different name for ```hidden```

Comment: @shrys, Did you check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API#Example?

Comment: @haim770 yes I did see that. I guess I should go with this implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Copying and correcting @haim770’s deleted answer for now:

> The purpose of [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is to check whether a certain property is defined on the object *itself* and is not inherited through its `prototype`.
>
> In the case of `document`, it rightfully returns `false` since the `hidden` property is actually defined on [`Document`] and not on [the document object] itself.

```js
console.log('' + Object.getPrototypeOf(document));
console.log('' + Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(document)));

console.log(document.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('hidden'));

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'hidden'));
```